# C: Parse empty tokens from a string with strtok

Tags: c, string

My application produces strings like the one below. I need to parse values between the separator into individual values.

```
2342|2sd45|dswer|2342||5523|||3654|Pswt
```

I am using `strtok` to do this in a loop. For the fifth token, I am getting 5523. However, I need to account for the empty value between the two separators `||` as well. 5523 should be the sixth token, as per my requirement.

```
token = (char *)strtok(strAccInfo, "|");

for (iLoop=1;iLoop<=106;iLoop++) { 
            token = (char *)strtok(NULL, "|");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: strtok() is arguably the worst thing in the C standard.  You could write your own parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that case I often prefer a `p2 = strchr(p1, '|')` loop with a `memcpy(s, p1, p2-p1)` inside. It's fast, does not destroy the input buffer (so it can be used with `const char *`) and is really portable (even on embedded).

It's also reentrant; `strtok` isn't. (BTW: reentrant has nothing to do with multi-threading. `strtok` breaks already with nested loops. One can use `strtok_r` but it's not as portable.)

Comment: I used your input and updated my code. Thanks! I have the code that I am using below as an answer, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, inspired by your answer I made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55544721/5407848)

Comment: Sorry Patrick but could you explain a bit in detail how your solution works? I'm guessing `s` is the original string, but what are `p1` and `p2`?

Answer (score 3):

```
char *mystrtok(char **m,char *s,char c)
{
  char *p=s?s:*m;
  if( !*p )
    return 0;
  *m=strchr(p,c);
  if( *m )
    *(*m)++=0;
  else
    *m=p+strlen(p);
  return p;
}
```

- reentrant
- threadsafe
- strictly ANSI conform
- needs an unused help-pointer from calling
  context

e.g.

```
char *p,*t,s[]="2342|2sd45|dswer|2342||5523|||3654|Pswt";
for(t=mystrtok(&p,s,'|');t;t=mystrtok(&p,0,'|'))
  puts(t);
```

e.g.

```
char *p,*t,s[]="2,3,4,2|2s,d4,5|dswer|23,42||5523|||3654|Pswt";
for(t=mystrtok(&p,s,'|');t;t=mystrtok(&p,0,'|'))
{
  char *p1,*t1;
  for(t1=mystrtok(&p1,t,',');t1;t1=mystrtok(&p1,0,','))
    puts(t1);
}
```

your work :)
implement char *c as parameter 3

Answer (score 2):

> On a first call, the function expects
>   a C string as argument for str, whose
>   first character is used as the
>   starting location to scan for tokens.
>   In subsequent calls, the function
>   expects a null pointer and uses the
>   position right after the end of last
>   token as the new starting location for
>   scanning.
>
> To determine the beginning and the end
>   of a token, the function first scans
>   from the starting location for the
>   first character not contained in
>   delimiters (which becomes the
>   beginning of the token). And then
>   scans starting from this beginning of
>   the token for the first character
>   contained in delimiters, which becomes
>   the end of the token.

What this say is that it will skip any '|' characters at the beginning of a token. Making 5523 the 5th token, which you already knew. Just thought I would explain why (I had to look it up myself). This also says that you will not get any empty tokens.

Since your data is setup this way you have a couple of possible solutions:
1) find all occurrences of || and replace with | |  (put a space in there)
2) do a strstr 5 times and find the beginning of the 5th element.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Hopefully, I will remember this the next time I need to. :-D
Your first solution screws up my results a bit, because there are valid components within the string that return a space between pipes. 
The second solution might become tedious and probably not implementable since the string may be different for different sets of data.

Comment: @Bash - Sorry I could not be of more help :(

Comment: oh, you were a lot of help...information is power in our field, right?

Answer (score 2):

That's a limitation of `strtok`. The designers had whitespace-separated tokens in mind. `strtok` doesn't do much anyway; just roll your own parser. The [C FAQ has an example](http://c-faq.com/lib/strtok.html).

Comment: I got some useful information from the link you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look into using strsep instead: [strsep reference](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html)

Comment: oh well :-) Most of my coding is on UNIX and that sure will come in handy right about now :-)) never heard of it before.

Answer (score 1):

Use something other than `strtok`. It's simply not intended to do what you're asking for. When I've needed this, I usually used `strcspn` or `strpbrk` and handled the rest of the tokeninzing myself. If you don't mind it modifying the input string like `strtok`, it should be pretty simple. At least right off, something like this seems as if it should work:

```
// Warning: untested code. Should really use something with a less-ugly interface.
char *tokenize(char *input, char const *delim) { 
    static char *current;    // just as ugly as strtok!
    char *pos, *ret;
    if (input != NULL)
        current = input;

    if (current == NULL)
        return current;

    ret = current;
    pos = strpbrk(current, delim);
    if (pos == NULL) 
        current = NULL;
    else {
        *pos = '\0';
        current = pos+1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Since the OP is only searching for one delimiter character, `strchr()` could be used instead of `strpbrk()`.

Comment: I did it a little different. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Patrick Schlüter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3375776/5407848) I made this function, it is supposed to be thread safe and support empty tokens and doesn't change the original string

```
char* strTok(char** newString, char* delimiter)
{
    char* string = *newString;
    char* delimiterFound = (char*) 0;
    int tokLenght = 0;
    char* tok = (char*) 0;

    if(!string) return (char*) 0;

    delimiterFound = strstr(string, delimiter);

    if(delimiterFound){
        tokLenght = delimiterFound-string;
    }else{
        tokLenght = strlen(string);
    }

    tok = malloc(tokLenght + 1);
    memcpy(tok, string, tokLenght);
    tok[tokLenght] = '\0';

    *newString = delimiterFound ? delimiterFound + strlen(delimiter) : (char*)0;

    return tok;
}
```

you can use it like

```
char* input = "1,2,3,,5,";
char** inputP = &input;
char* tok;
while( (tok=strTok(inputP, ",")) ){
    printf("%s\n", tok);
}
```

This suppose to output

```
1
2
3

5
```

I tested it for simple strings but didn't use it in production yet, and posted it on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216956/strtok-function-thread-safe-supports-empty-tokens-doesnt-change-string) too, so you can see what do others think about it

Comment: If you're on a Posix machine you can replace the 'tok = malloc(tokLenght + 1); memcpy(tok, string, tokLenght);    tok[tokLenght] = '\0';'` simply by `tok = strndup(string, tokLength);`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution that is working for me now. Thanks to all of you who responded.

I am using LoadRunner. Hence, some unfamiliar commands, but I believe the flow can be understood easily enough.

```
char strAccInfo[1024], *p2;
int iLoop;

Action() {  //This value would come from the wrsp call in the actual script.
    lr_save_string("323|90||95|95|null|80|50|105|100|45","test_Param");

    //Store the parameter into a string - saves memory. 
    strcpy(strAccInfo,lr_eval_string("{test_Param}"));
    //Get the first instance of the separator "|" in the string
    p2 = (char *) strchr(strAccInfo,'|');

    //Start a loop - Set the max loop value to more than max expected.
    for (iLoop = 1;iLoop<200;iLoop++) { 

        //Save parameter names in sequence.
        lr_param_sprintf("Param_Name","Parameter_%d",iLoop);

        //Get the first instance of the separator "|" in the string (within the loop).
        p2 = (char *) strchr(strAccInfo,'|');           

        //Save the value for the parameters in sequence. 
        lr_save_var(strAccInfo,p2 - strAccInfo,0,lr_eval_string("{Param_Name}"));   

        //Save string after the first instance of p2, as strAccInfo - for looping.
        strcpy(strAccInfo,p2+1);

        //Start conditional loop for checking for last value in the string.
        if (strchr(strAccInfo,'|')==NULL) {
            lr_param_sprintf("Param_Name","Parameter_%d",iLoop+1);
            lr_save_string(strAccInfo,lr_eval_string("{Param_Name}"));
            iLoop = 200;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At some point, you need to explain why you have global variables instead of local variables, and why you don't have a return type on the function (that's very old style C).  Or, better, just fix the code so it compiles cleanly under stringent compiler warnings.  The use of `iLoop = 200;` to achieve `break;` is fragile.  It is not clear why 200 is used in the loop control anyway.